# Self joins and eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a user table that holds all my users. My application allows parents and their children via their own email addresses, but I need to be able to say that "child 1, is a related to parent 1 and parent 2" I want to store all this in the same table, it seems like it's a many-many relationship in so much as many users can belong to any number of other users.

How would I represent an internal many-many relationship in eloquent?

I hitting nothing but net with my attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think you'd represent this the same way you would any other many-to-many relationship; only difference is that the same `User` model holds both the default and inverse relationship:

```
public function parents(){
   return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, "users_users", "user_id", "parent_id");
}

public function children(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, "users_users", "parent_id", "user_id");
}
```

Note: I may have `user_id` and `parent_id` backwards, but that can be adjusted easily.

The only catch I can see with this is trying to get children of children recursively, if that's a concern, but otherwise, this should work for a basic many-to-many.

Comment: so I would need a users_users pivot table?

Comment: Yup :) Just like any `many-to-many`, you'd need a pivot table, so `users_users`, with at a minimum, `parent_id` and `user_id`